# Lstat error for filetype(). Followed example from php.net

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to fetch directory data from a file.

**Desired behaviour** I want to the code to echo out the directory. I'll eventually put it all in an array.

**Issue** I am getting several Warning: filetype(): Lstat failed errors. All of this is tested on WAMP.

here is my code:

```
    $dir = "../images/";


echo $dir;

if (is_dir($dir)){
   if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while ($file = readdir($dh) !== false){
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: ". filetype($dir . $file). "</br>";
        }
    closedir($dr);

        }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't forget to the `.` and `..` that come in first. Test for them.

```
<?php
....
if (is_dir($dir)){
  $dh=opendir($dir);
  while ($file = readdir ($dir)) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        echo "filename: $file : filetype: ". filetype($dir . $file)."</br>";
    }
  }
  closedir($dh);
}
?>
```

Update

**To test the script put it one level above folder `images`** and try this :

```
<?php
chdir ('images');
$dh=opendir('.');
while ($file = readdir ($dh)) {
   if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        echo "filename: $file : filetype: ". filetype($file)."</br>";
    }
}
  closedir($dh);
?>
```

Question

> Why to use `if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {`

`readdir() show also if there are above levels of the directory`

so the first you get with  `readdir()` is

- 1.) `'.'`
- 2.) `'..'`
- 3.) `afile.jpg`

Comment: So I've followed your code and fixed. closedir($dh); but now nothing pops up. I'm guessing it's not passing. Why isn't it?

Comment: @JPFoster : my code should only show where you have to put the `if()` statement. Put only the `if($file != "."...) { your code }` in your initial code.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. What do you mean by "the best put the script one level above and then"?  I tried to move the directory to /images to make sure the directory was correct and no output (and there are picture files in the folder).

I have not tried chdir function though. where would i put the second piece of code? Before the first if statement?

Comment: Oh wait! I changed the code, it works. It echos the directory. Thanks so much!

Turns out I didn't notice your while statement change. What does $file != ".." do? or $file != ".". Why would I need that?

Comment: @JPFoster : please look at my update `Why to use ..`